# How to split this YAML file into two new yml files?

Tags: python, split, yaml

I'm trying to split a yml file into two new yml files. The first file consists only of the keys and the second file consists only of the values.

This is my code:

```
# Import
from itertools import zip_longest
import yaml
import re

# Saves values to another yml file
with open("testFile.yml") as a_file:
  for object in a_file:
    stripped_object = object.rstrip()
    found = False
    file = open("ValuesfileNotTranslated.yml", "a")
    if re.split(':|=', stripped_object, maxsplit=1)[-1].strip():
      file.writelines(re.split(':|=', stripped_object, maxsplit=1)[-1].strip() + "\n" )

# Saves keys to another yml file
with open("testFile.yml") as a_file:
  for object in a_file:
    if object[:object.find(":")]:
      file = open("Keysfile.yml", "a")
      file.writelines(object[:object.find(":")] + ":" + "\n")
    else:
      file.writelines(object)
```

This is the yml file that I want to split:

```
 channels:
      channel: Channel
      headline: Channels
      empty_msg: There are currently no channels.
      add: Add new channel
      reorder: Change channel order
      actions:
        show: View
        edit: Edit
        remove: Remove
```

When I try to run the code I get thes 2 outputs:

- File 1: consists only of the keys (This file is correct)

```
channels:
      channel:
      headline:
      empty_msg:
      add:
      reorder:
      actions:
        show:
        edit:
        remove:
```

**Note:** There are 10 lines.

- File 2: consists only of the values (This file is not correct)

```
Channel
Channels
There are currently no channels.
Add new channel
Change channel order
View
Edit
Remove
```

**Note:** There are only 8 lines.
The second file should also be 10 lines. For example *line 3* in *file 1* must match *line 3* in *file 2* (for example "headline" = "Channels")

When we look at the input yml file:

```
channels:
      channel: Channel
```

We see for example these 2 first lines. "Channels:" and "channel" is being saved to the keys file, but the only thing that is saved to the values file is "channel". So the whitespace after "channels:" is not being saved to the values file. I think there is the problem, but I can't figure out what I have to change in my code to get the right output.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: When you use `rstrip()`, you're stripping away all the whitespace after the last non-whitespace character in the line, so when you try to run `re.split()` on it, it only returns 1 result instead of two.

Comment: @MattDMo But when I delete `rstrip()` nothing happens. When I delete `rstrip()` and `strip()`, an extra whitespace is created.

Answer (score 0):

Regexes should do the job:

```py
import re

regex_first_part  = r"(.*)(?=:)"
regex_second_part = r":.*$"

test_str = (" channels:\n"
    "      channel: Channel\n"
    "      headline: Channels\n"
    "      empty_msg: There are currently no channels.\n"
    "      add: Add new channel\n"
    "      reorder: Change channel order\n"
    "      actions:\n"
    "        show: View\n"
    "        edit: Edit\n"
    "        remove: Remove")

matches = re.findall(regex_first_part, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
# Lets remove the empty lines and make a string with the output
first_part = "\n".join(list(filter(None, matches)))

print(first_part)

matches = re.findall(regex_second_part, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
second_part = [m.replace(':', '').strip() for m in matches]
second_part = "\n".join(second_part)

print(second_part)
```

output:

```sh
 channels
      channel
      headline
      empty_msg
      add
      reorder
      actions
        show
        edit
        remove

Channel
Channels
There are currently no channels.
Add new channel
Change channel order

View
Edit
Remove
```

Try it yourself [here](https://tio.run/##fVJdS8MwFH02v@JShaaj9MW3wBCRPQzmHmT64scIzd0abZOS3Fn362u6rbMVtNCmnHvOzTk3qfdUWHPdtrqqrSNwyJjDLX6tN9p5WtcygDAFF73xbJLwm6lIohPDY26NOlI6hsgmVxFjhEHnyQWMR5AX0hgsvXgxEbuI4PCcQAF3x59hrUCpSm3wXPTDKlY17deV3wpYFegQZHjznXNoqNyDsecNs6FMKiXgVikw2PSMYd2hdQrdcc8t9hQ4oKNGOWlrxmkAfGEbAU8amzGOSpOAWfiOcYeV/QwJHw5rlDBWScoL9N0cMdtoo2RZ8t8HkUI/27Sj3T8uVvPFfDlL2CUskPypL1CBx0FBN0gP0iio5EcYFgStNltoNBUHmt1RvSM2OOwpRMFs9m614aX2xDe6JHR8aQ2mcPKZJMFzHVp15V76f4zBbfk7x/hKPVeZw7qUOfJYxCnEcZJ1AWqewMY6qECb3tHrL@1PiAF@Nj3E2vYb)

### Analysis

- We compute a first regex to get all lines starting by any characters, and we stop just before the ":"
- We remove the empty lines if we have some
- We join the result to have our first part.
- We compute a second regex that will get the end of all lines that have a ":", with the ":" (To get at least one char everytime)
- We remove the ":" from each line, and trim the leading spaces
- We join the result to have our second part.

Here are the regexes:

[first part](https://regex101.com/r/rPfXka/1)

[second part](https://regex101.com/r/1Y2uyt/1)

> Note: If you want to keep the ":" at the end of each line in the first part, just replace first regex by  `r"(.*):"`

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the if and you will be ok.

```
with open("testFile.yml") as a_file:
    for object in a_file:
        stripped_object = object.rstrip()
        found = False
        file = open("ValuesfileNotTranslated.yml", "a")
        file.writelines(re.split(':|=', stripped_object, maxsplit=1)[-1].strip() + "\n" )
```

Also, if you open the file just once the solution will be more efficent